# Understanding GroupComparator

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am dealing with a secondary sort problem, Consider the data below, by the way values can be NullWritable.

```
 Composite key 
    2000 250     
    2000 150
    2000 90

    2001 100
    2001 80

    2002 500
    2002 120
```

My composite key is made up year(ascending) and number of students(descending). So according to what I read if I group the key by year then in my reducer I should get the maximum value  of each year in my output since the second part of my composite is sorted in descending order. I don't understand the logic behind this because I cannot see which part of the key will be sent to the reducer or how the grouping is done.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188971/secondary-sorting-in-map-reduce - I added some additional explaination at your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire key will be sent to the reducer. The `GroupingComparator` determines which keys are "the same" for purposes of knowing which values go together into one call to `reduce`. If your grouping only groups on year, then yes several keys, and all their values, will go into one `reduce`. I believe the actual key you see will be the very first one in the group only, yes.

Whether that makes sense for you here I don't know. I don't even know if it's defined which key you get since you are saying they're all "the same" to you within a group.

Usually I have used this mechanism to provide a faster, low-level comparator implementation, not to make one with unusual semantics.

If you just want your `Reducer` to see keys in sorted order, well it will already. It can remember the last values it saw for example. If you need all keys starting with 2000 to go to the same `Reducer` for example, that's a job for the partitioner, not grouping comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Grouping key determines the part of the key for which the reduce method will be called at one go.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a group comparator it will decide the values that will go to the **reduce** method parameter **Iterable values** for the key.

```
void reduce(key, Iterable<> values, Context){}
```

In your case if you do grouping on Year 2001 the values 100 and 80 will go.

If you write a custom partitioner it will decide the values that go to reducer based on key you gave in your custom partitioner.